# how to set commas in prettier vs code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, prettier

I have css file. I want to set prettier vs code so that after writing a comma, the selector I wrote remained in line with the previous selector. But when i save the file, the selector will be entered to next line

I want to save the code like this (my expectation)

[image]

But prettier set the code like this (h3 entered to next line)
[image]

How to fix this problem? I set trailling comma to none but it doesn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that config you changed only applies to JavaScript files (notice the reference to ES5).

As far as CSS, prettier is [opinionated](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3464#issuecomment-351146227) and they decided that each selector should have its own line ([this PR implements that behaviour](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/2047)). I don't think there's a config to change that behaviour.